# converting td value in textbox to edit and display the same

Tags: php, jquery

I have one column as remark, I want a user to let enter remark whatever they want and it should b displayed every time they see this table  I searched a lot and at last using this code but it is not working as well,when user click on remark ,it should b editable ,but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mylist_remark').on('click', '.Edit', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').each(function() {
            // replace the existing text with a textbox containing that text
            var existingVal = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + existingVal + '" >');
        });
    });

    // when the user is finished editing, change the value and remove the textbox,and display edited text
    $('#mylist_remark').on('focusout', 'td input', function() {
        $(this).parent().html( this.value );
    });
});
```

The script

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

TABLE CODE

```
    <table id="mylist_remark">
    <caption>SELECTED CANDIDATE LIST</caption>
    <!-- headings -->
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th>REMARK</th>
        </tr>
   <?php $i=0;
    while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($mresult_set))
        {     
            echo "<tr id=\"{$listrowid}\">";                                
            echo "<td><a href\"\" class=\"Edit\">remark</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;                       
            }?>
    </table>
```

THANKS

Comment: How is your code even rendering without php tags?

Comment: Where is the query? "$mresult_set"?

Comment: I am not fetching anything related to remark so i have not given that ,shall I include that here?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing all of this, have you considered using the "contenteditable" attribute?

```
<td class="editable" contenteditable="true">Something</td>

$("#mylist_remark .editable").bind("blur", function(e) { 
  console.log($(e.target).text());
  $.post("/somewhere", {remark: $(e.target).text(), candidate_id: $(e.target).nearest("tr").attr("id")}, function() { console.log("success"); });
  //save the result to the server or whatever you need to do to make it persist
});
```

You'd also want to bind "enter" and "escape" keydown events.

Comment: this allow me to edit text,but when form reloads again than that edited text is not getting displayed ,how can i achieve that?  and i didn't got this point "You'd also want to bind "enter" and "escape" keydown events." ,how can i do this

Comment: i tried this within your code but this is not working `var value = $(this).val();$(".editable").text(value);`

Comment: This would enable you to edit the text, but you'd still need to store those changes somewhere - posting it to the server, or adding it to localstorage. I'll do an edit.

Comment: I've shown how to get the remark text and post it to the server - you'll need to do something serverside to store the result and display on subsequent requests.

Comment: i know i am asking very basic question ,but as i am new to this can you please tell that `"/somewhere"` should be some .php file or some database column or folder, what it should be

Comment: I mean how can I link to  `"/somewhere"`  means if it is URL than how can i write this ,page that contains this code has a name csearch.php than what URL i should write,and what if i don't want to store it somewhere else ,and i store it on same page?

Comment: Sorry, I think you're asking for something much bigger than a stack overflow answer! I think you need to do some reading and research...

Comment: OK , Thanks for your response ,but I searched ,and even tried storing it in `store.php` file  but i didn't got required solution